# Swift method passing NSLocalizedString to NSObject parameter won't compile

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, nsobject

I had to modify an Objective-C method to take an `NSObject` parameter which is actually expected to be an `NSString` or an `NSLocalizedString`. Originally the method was declared to take an `NSString` parameter, but I needed the flexibility of being able to pass either an `NSString` or an `NSLocalizedString`, which I found to  my dismay only have `NSObject` as a common ancestor.

This change to the parameter type of the Objective-C method has introduced problems into some existing Swift code that calls the method with an `NSLocalizededString` parameter passed in as:

```
NSLocalizedString('random key', comment: 'Key name')
```

Here's the actual code, which I don't think will be more enlightening:

```
appDelegate.menuOverlayViewController.showPopup(withStateName: "didRequestTrackChange", 
withTitle: NSLocalizedString("localization.popup.title", comment: "Success!"), 
withIconName: "icon_like", 
withBody:body)
```

Unmodified, the code is producing this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSObject!'

if I try to cast the `NSLocalizedString` to an `NSObject` like so:

```
NSObject(NSLocalizedString('random key', comment: 'Key name'))
```

I run into the following error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

How can I fix this? I am relatively new to Swift so don't understand the nuances of how I would cast something or why an `NSLocalizedString` is apparently being turned into a Swift `String` even before getting passed to a parameter of type `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Swift `String` is not an object, but a `struct`.  If you want to use `NSObject` for both `NSString` and `NSLocalizedString`, cast the Swift `String` as `NSString`.

```
"my string" as NSString
```

Or, consider using a protocol and extending both `NSString` and `NSLocalizedString` to conform to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
NSObject(NSLocalizedString('random key', comment: 'Key name'))
```

try

```
(NSString(string :NSLocalizedString('random key', comment: 'Key name'))
```

Edit: What about

```
NSLocalizedString('random key', comment: 'Key name') as! NSObject
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this also gives `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSObject!'`

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Why would you initialize a new `NSObject` from `NSString` or `NSLocalizedString`?

Comment: @JAL it does make sense and it works great in Objective-C, simply not in this Swift code I didn't write that I now have to adapt.

Comment: How does it make sense in Objective-C?  `NSString` and `NSLocalizedString` are already `NSObject` subclasses.  Why would you initialize a **new** `NSObject` just to wrap it?